# Rejected Fetch Promise: access to response text

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, responsetext

I’m using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to load some JSON. Therefore, I use [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) on the response stream and also the optional second function argument (`onRejected`) in [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), which has only one argument, the rejection reason.

If something goes wrong (like the response being no valid JSON), I want access to the raw response text to have some meaningful error log or to further process the unexpected response.

Consider this simplified snippet:

```javascript
fetch('api.php')
.then(
    response => { return response.json(); }
)
.then(
    json => { /* useful fulfillment value, a JSON object */ },
    reason => { /* string message only */ }
);
```

If the API responds with something other than valid JSON, it will reject with the following reason:

> *SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*

While this is a perfectly clear error message, it lacks a dump of what actually *caused* the error.

I considered using [`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) and then trying to parse the JSON myself, but that would somewhat contravene the purpose of `.json()`.

**Is there a reasonable way to access the response text if stream-reading is rejected?**

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content type:

```
  var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
  if(contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
       response => { return response.json(); }
  }
  else{
       response => { return response.text(); }
  }
```

---

If you want to get the response in the rejection callback you can do something like this

```
  response => { 
          var text = '';
          try{
              text= response.json(); 
          }
          catch (e if e instanceof SyntaxError) {
             text = response.text();
          } 
          return text;
  }
```

Comment: That would be an easy, secure way to ensure the response gets to processing, but it would require checking if the argument actually *was* JSON. I could use `.text()` right away. The question was if there's some way to access the response in the rejection callback.

Comment: What about a try..catch like above?

Comment: Have you tried it? It still calls the rejection function, probably because no reassignment takes place after the response stream has been read to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is nasty but could solve the problem:

```
let res;
fetch('api.php')
.then(
    response => { res = response; return response.json(); }
)
.then(
    json => { /* useful fulfillment value, a JSON object */ },
    reason => { /* use res variable */ }
);
```